# Drawing a binary tree in Scheme

Tags: tree, racket

I have seen that in Scheme a binary tree like this:

```
           5
      3          8
   1     4    6      9
```

I can represent it with a list of lists like the following:

'(5 (3 (1 () ()) (4 () ())) (8 (6 () ()) (9 () ())))

which resembles me the Newick format, but this is used for unrooted trees. I would like to know if there is a simple way to visualize this tree based on lists in Scheme or Racket. Is there not a tree viewer based on lists like the one in: http://etetoolkit.org/treeview/ ?

Comment: You can use the `graphviz` package to create a visualization of a graph easily. Alternatively, you can use `racket/draw` to draw the graph directly.

Comment: See [Visualize arbitrary tree in Racket using tree-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621805/visualize-arbitrary-tree-in-racket-using-tree-layout/) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite easy.  Here is something moderately horrible (the horror is in the half-cooked attempt to abstract away the explicit listy representation):

```
(require pict
         pict/tree-layout)

(define (show-tree tree
                   #:node-null? (node-null? null?)
                   #:node? (node? list?)
                   #:node-value (node-value first)
                   #:node-children (node-children rest))
  (define (tree-layout* this children)
    (apply tree-layout children #:pict this))
  (define (show/r node)
    (unless (node? node)
      (error 'show-tree "~A isn't a node" node))
    (if (node-null? node)
        #f
        (tree-layout* (cc-superimpose
                       (disk 20 #:color "white")
                       (text (format "~A" (node-value node))))
                     (map show/r (node-children node)))))
  (naive-layered (show/r tree)))
```

This will draw trees which are not binary trees, but it will have trouble with nodes whose values are longer than it expects them to be: I've always found Racket's tree-layout algorithm a bit inflexible about that sort of thing, but I probably just don't understand it.